# Problem getting into our website from within the network

Tags: networking, iis

we have a domain and it is the same network domain.
if i try the website with "www" it will work and go to the iis server xxx.xxx.xxx.174 but without the "www" it will go to the xxx.xxx.xxx.175 (the active directory and dns of the network) and becuase that there is no iis website set on it it will show iis under construction error.

what can we do?

Comment: Hey...dude...accept some answers...I'm skipping this question because your lack of rewards doesn't meet my requirements for incentives...Check this link out http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: how can i accept answers if i have never got any that helped solve my problem?

Comment: YGJ - The first question I saw in your profile has a few correct answers posted on it regarding SSL certificates.  Might be time to go review your previous questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the domain in question your Active Directory domain (i.e. acme.local)?  If yes, there's a reason why that resolves to your DC/DNS server and should stay that way.

Having said that, you can certainly create as many A records as you want internally in DNS on your domain: i.e. if it's an intranet there's no reason why you can't create `intranet A xx.xx.xx.174` and have www.acme.local as a CNAME to 'intranet'.

If you absolutely must have acme.local go to your website, you could edit the default.htm in your DC/DNS Server's Default Website in IIS and put in a meta refresh tag or do a permanent redirect (301) as such in IIS 6 (I think IIS 7 is the same):

1. Right-click > properties of the Default Web Site
2. Home Directory tab > click "A redirection to a URL" and enter in www.acme.local in "Redirect To" field.
3. Check "A Permanent redirection for this resource".  Ok and close out. Might have to restart IIS, can't remember.

Comment: +1 - Why do people persist in naming their AD domains the same as their Internet-facing domain names? All it does is create stupid make-work. Microsoft has recommended against this practice since Windows 2000 was released, yet it still happens (and people keep saying "It's no big deal-- after seeing 20+ DC's in a single enterprise all running "redirects" like gravyface describes I can safely say it's a non-trivial problem).

Comment: Tell me about it.  Thankfully SBS uses the .local TLD by default.

Comment: But .local has problems too, especially if there are Macs in the network. My preference is for a subdomain of the real domain, like corp.contoso.com.

Comment: this is something i was thinking about - redirecting... but i wanted to see if there is something else...

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is to put a redirecting site in the IIS root that redirects all traffic to "www.domain.co.il".

Answer (score 0):

First mistake is naming your outgoing domain same as internal domain. You can simply make them seperate ;) Like outgoing: something.com and internal: something.pvt or something.com.local. Just differ your name ;)

Second mistake is using AD's DNS as your outgoing DNS... Always use another configured DNS server which faces the internet, and to achieve that you should name your domains differently ;) And configure that outsider DNS to relay internal queries to AD's DNS... ( redirect x.y.local to IP(a.b.c.d) )

About the problem, x.y is your ACTUAL DOMAIN, so any query asks for x.y domain, always {should} go(es) to your AD's DNS, and because of the AD behaviour, it will resolve to the address of DC and you'll get that DC's IP adress ;) ( this will be more and more annoying when you have multiple DCs, because there's a very good chance to get different IPs {which will be that DCs ;) } ) And there it comes the 3rd mistake: Entering a host record "www" to DC's DNS that faces to outside... When a www.x.y query comes, DC's DNS will resolve that corretly, but, IT IS your DC! Your hearth, your center point! ( this is connected to second mistake i mentioned above ) And of course, semanticly, you'll want to query x.y to get your web server but no, what will return to you is your DC...

About the solution, you'll have to configure the IIS on that DC and redirect your default site to your actual web server ( www.x.y ) ( like "gravyface" explained ) unless you dont want to deploy a second DNS server to your network to achieve this Front-end Back-end acrhitecture...